# How to load an svg to CanvasVirtualControl in C++/winrt?

Tags: svg, uwp, c++-winrt

I've been loading drawing svg images successfully in a UWP app built with C++/winrt but in the latest release find that the call to load the svg throws an exception.
The crash happens in an IAsync method that is hard to trace, but I've narrowed the problem down to the one line that loads the SVG.

This is normally looping to read lots of files, but very simple reduction of the problem still displays the issue:

```
winrt::Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasVirtualControl resourceCreator
winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile nextFile = nullptr;
winrt::Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::Svg::CanvasSvgDocument nextSvg = nullptr;
winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream  fileStream = nullptr;

//This is called from within the lambda handling CreateResources for the CanvasVirtualControl
//The VirtualControl is provided as the resourceCreator argument

IAsyncAction loadSVGs(winrt::Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::UI::Xaml::CanvasVirtualControl resourceCreator)
{
nextFile = m_symbol_resource_files.GetAt(i);
fileStream = co_await nextFile.OpenReadAsync();
nextSvg = co_await CanvasSvgDocument::LoadAsync(resourceCreator,fileStream);
}
```

The call to LoadAsync fails with

```
exception: winrt:hresult_invalid_argument at memory location 0x0C93F1CB
void resume()const{
->_coro_resume(_Ptr);
}
```

If I continue past the exception I find that the resource has in fact loaded and is usable. But if running outside Visual Studio the app will often quit at this line. Could it be that the CanvasVirtualControl is not acceptable?

Or is there a better way to load the svg from file? I haven't been able to work out the CanvasDocument's LoadFromXML, as it takes a System.String argument not available in C++/winrt and the winrt std::wstring is not acceptable as a substitute [Correction: in fact hstring will work as an argument and that can be created from std::wstring].

[Update]I have not yet created a simple demo project displaying this behavior, but I think I have a line on the cause and would like to extend my question. I've tried both the LoadFromXml and the LoadAsync methods of the CanvasSvgDocument, and the second of these used to be fine, but now both fail the same way and it seems to me that the ResourceCreator argument may be the trouble. I am creating these resources in the CreateResources handler and I pass the sender - CanvasVirtualControl - as the resourceCreator. The listed argument for both the CanvasSvgDocument calls, however, is ICanvasResourceCreator. I had thought this was a convenience and that the CanvasVirtualControl could be passed directly for that argument (and so it used to be). But perhaps this is incorrect, maybe always was and is now being noticed as incorrect? If so, how would the sender in the CreateResources handler properly be passed to the CanvasSvgDocument method?

Comment: There is probably a lifetime issue somewhere in your code. We need a [mcve] to help you solve that. [CanvasSvgDocument.LoadFromXml](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Svg_CanvasSvgDocument_LoadFromXml.htm) takes a `String` parameter. That maps to `System.String` when using .NET (but it really isn't). It's still an [HSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winrt/hstring), conveniently wrapped in an [hstring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/hstring) struct in C++/WinRT.

Comment: Thanks for the hstring note - somehow that hadn't seemed to work the first time I tried it and you are right. I'd like to add to my question and ask about the ResourceCreator argument. I'll edit the question for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a blank app to use CanvasVirtualControl to load SVG, it worked well. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced? And I checked the LoadFromXML method, the parameter it needs is hstring type instead of System.String.

In addition, about loading the svg from file, do you have to use win2d to load svg? If not, you could try to use Image control by [SvgImageSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.svgimagesource) to load svg, like below:

.xaml:

```
<Image x:Name="MyImage" Width="300" Height="200"></Image>
```

.cpp:

```
winrt::Windows::Storage::StorageFile nextFile = nullptr;
winrt::Microsoft::Graphics::Canvas::Svg::CanvasSvgDocument nextSvg = nullptr;
winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IRandomAccessStream  fileStream = nullptr;

nextFile = co_await KnownFolders::PicturesLibrary().GetFileAsync(L"Freesample.svg");
fileStream = co_await nextFile.OpenReadAsync();

SvgImageSource sourcee = SvgImageSource();
co_await sourcee.SetSourceAsync(fileStream);
MyImage().Source(sourcee);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into providing a short sample. I do need to use CanvasVirtualControl and the odd thing is that this was working. But I notice there is a common element: whether I load the svg from a filestream or with the LoadFromXml method, the same error occurs. The common element is the resourceCreator argument. I've been simply passing the CanvasVirtualControl provided as Sender in the CreateResources event. I wonder if something could have changed about the acceptability of that as a ResourceCreator.

Comment: I created a CreateResources event and passed the CanvasVirtualControl as sender, it worked well. There is a [simple sample](https://github.com/msdnwptest/UWP-Support-Samples/tree/master/SVG-WinRT-app) I created, you can checked it.

Comment: Thanks very much. Is there a way for me to download that project as a .zip? Also, I notice that the test .svg file is not included - do you know whether that file is UTF-8 or UTF-16? My svg files are UTF-8.

Comment: I may have found it. It appears that if I use a LE UTF-16 svg file then there is no exception thrown. If I can confirm that this is the issue I will change all 241 of these files to that format. CanvasSvgDocument says it supports both UTF-8 and UTF-16 for input, and as I mentioned, this code used to work - is there any chance that something in the OS has changed recently so that CanvasSvgDocument can no longer accept UTF-8?

Comment: This is a [zip file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An0w-GDe7v_shhPDgcajg3m41okz?e=2Upvd1) you can download it to check. I have put my Freesample.svg in it and it is utf-8 format, when CanvasSvgDocument load it, it worked well. You can replace your utf-8 file with it and see if the exception occurs. If occurs, can you provide your utf-8 file for us to test?

Comment: I appreciate that effort. The app runs, but the conditions are a little different because the exception settings are not the same in your project as in mine - I turned on some extra exceptions when my app began failing certification. It's not so easy for me to run the cert kit on the test. Does the test app get through the App Cert Kit without error?

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer because you have provided such a clear example of how to load an svg, which of course was the question. My theory about 8 vs 16 bits was wrong; I think the trouble was a result of wrong use of co_awaits in my loading loop, and so far it appears to be going better. No crash when loading the svgs now; just need to make sure they're all loading correctly.

Comment: So the trouble is about co_await instead of turning on some extra exceptions?

Comment: Apparently so - I tried setting the same exceptions in your sample project and they were not thrown. I think this had something to do with nested co_awaits in my loading loop, and though I'm not quite done with it I think it is going to work. I don't have a clear enough idea of the cause to explain it better than that. The async stuff is tricky to debug.

Comment: [Update - running into the same problem again. What a mystery. Seems that the loading of the images does not complete. About half of them are loaded, then when trying to trace the list I can encounter the same exceptions. I had thought that each co_await would not begin until the previous had completed, so that one could depend on the result of the previous one, but something is getting tangled.]

Comment: [Update 2] I may have to ask a separate question about looping with co_awaits, and how to call such a loop inside a method that does not itself return an IAsync result, etc.

Comment: @use: You are probably capturing variables by reference in your lambda, either explicitly or implicitly. References and coroutines do not go well together. Once you hit a suspension point, your references are potentially dangling references. We'll still need to see a [mcve] to answer that question, though.

Comment: Thanks for that, IInspectable.. I seem to have fixed the problem with some small changes to the loop, updating Win2D, and removing an svg that Canvas didn't seem to like (but which displays in Edge!). But I hope it's not problematic to call a method from within the lambda to handle all the work - passing the sender as the only argument.